# Multideep django query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```py
class AttributeType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Attribute(models.Model): # Server attributes                                                                                                                                                                                  
    name = models.ForeignKey(MiscType)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then I want to create a loop, which should loop trough every attributes, and find each server
which have one or two attributes, like:

```py
output = []
for attribute in AttributeType.objects.all():
    for a in Server.attributes.filter(name__name=attribute.name):
         output.append(str(a))
```

How can I do this most efficient? Currently, it will run one query per inner loop.

An output like this would be what I want:

> [ {'server1': [{'attribute1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], 'attribute2':
>   ['val1', 'val2']}, 'server2':....} ]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best you can do is something like this! so it will return all systems at once! but you still have to do 2 queries! which is not a big deal, MySQL sometimes behaviour better having 2 queries then one with a lot JOINs.

```
att = AttributeType.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
for a in Server.attributes.filter(name__name__in=att):
     output.append(str(a))
```

Comment: I have to get the name of each attribute based on which attribute is in the loop (its a part of a bigger loop). So I cant use __in.. I basicly wants a list where I have one server per row, and one column per attribute, where it is commaseparated if there is more than one attribute with the same name for one server.

Comment: but you have to display all the attributs for each server right?(as your exmple) so you can grab the att names from the servers! and iterate over then to display them!

Comment: Yea, I haveto display all attributes for each server.. The trick is that there can be multiple of the same attribute. And in cases like that, I need to create a comma separate list. So I need to have them available at the same time as in the first example

Answer (score 0):

First collect all the attributes you want to get e.g.

```
attributes = set()
for x in mybigloop:
    attributes.add(attr)
```

Then query them all at once

```
for a in Server.attributes.filter(name__in=attributes):
    output.append(str(a))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but not quite what I wanted.. See comment on the first answer

Comment: @xeor i don't quite understand your comment there, why can't you collect attributes and then query, can you give a simple example why that is not possible in your case?

Comment: Since there can be more than 1 entry with each attribute. I would need to grab them all for all servers somehow.. I thought about a "maybe solution" for my problem. If I take the foreignkey out of the server class, I can store all mappings in an attributeMappings table. Then use select_releate to grab them. Dunno if this work as expected yet tough..